# Edit Attribution

Tags: discussion, edits, attribution

I had [asked/answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds) a question some time time ago and I recently noticed an edit that contains attribution to the editor. Looking at the [revision log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17474413/revisions) I noticed that a user who I assume approved the edit (*edit 8*) further edited to add the original editors user name.

I have not yet confirmed the edit, and have no reason to think that it is incorrect, but I was just wondering if it is a common practice to attribute edits, or does the revision log and comments serve this purpose?

Comment: Edit 8 seems like pure noise to me. The revision history should be enough (nothing official about this, just how I see it)

Comment: It is not a common practice and serves no purpose.  Just edit it out.

Answer (score 16):

> if it is a common practice to attribute edits

No. Edits should never have inline attribution, any more than posts should contain signatures or taglines. This is noise, and it should be rolled back.

Comment: Thank you. Someone has already rolled it back for me. Perhaps this should be added to the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). In this case it was not the editor, but the approver that seemed to make a mistake, but I was unable to find any documentation giving me the fuel to roll it back.